# Bash sed implementation replace with semi-colon

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to automate an install script for New Relic and in my bash file I have the following:

```
_APPNAME="Test Application"

_OLD=";newrelic.appname = \"PHP Application\""
_NEW="newrelic.appname = \"${_APPNAME}\""

sed -i 's/$_OLD/$_NEW/g' /etc/php.d/newrelic.ini
```

For some reason that sed command doesn't trigger at all, can anyone see anything wrong with this logic?

Note I have also tried `${_OLD}` and `${_NEW}` to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_OLD` and `$_NEW` are not expanded inside single quotes. `'`

Use double quotes `"` instead:

```
sed -i "s/$_OLD/$_NEW/g" /etc/php.d/newrelic.ini
```